# Prove if $w(x,y)=k$ is a charactheristic curve of $(1)$ iff $w(x,y)=k$ is a solution of the equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, proof-explanation

**Theorem:** Let $w\colon\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ a function that satisfies the characteristic equation $A(w_x)^2+Bw_x w_y+C(w_y)^2=0$ associated to the PDE with constant coefficients

$$A\frac{\partial{^2u}}{\partial{x}^2}+B\frac{\partial{^2u}}{\partial{x}\partial{y}}+C\frac{\partial{^2u}}{\partial{y^2}}+D\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{y}}+E\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}}+Fu=G \tag 1$$

Let $k$ constant. Prove if $w(x,y)=k$ is a characteristic curve of $(1)$ if and only if $w(x,y)=k$ is a solution of the equation

$A\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2-B\frac{dy}{dx}+C=0 \tag 2$

> I found the proof in a book but i don't understand some parts of the proof.

**Proof:**

$(\implies )$

Suppose $w_y\not = 0$.

By hypothesis $w(x,y)=k$ is a characteristic curve of $(1)$ then $w$ satisfies the equation
$$A(w_x)^2+Bw_xw_y+C(w_y)^2=0 \tag 3$$

> By implicit theorem we have:
>
> $$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{w_x}{w_y} \tag 4$$

Dividing each term of $(3)$ by $(w_y)^2$ we have:

$$A\left(\frac{w_x}{w_y}\right)^2+B\frac{w_x}{w_y}+C=0 \tag 5$$

Then, by $(4)$ we have:

$$A\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2-B\frac{dy}{dx}+C=0 $$

**In this proof. I cannot understand how he use the theorem of implicit function. I don't see that the hypotheses are fulfilled in order to use the theorem.**

($\Leftarrow$)

Suppose $w_y\not = 0$

Then, by implicit function theorem we have:

$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{w_x}{w_y} \tag 6$

By hypothesis we have $w(x,y)=k$ is a solution of the equation $(2)$

Then, by $(6)$ we have:

$0=A(\frac{dy}{dx})^2-B\frac{dy}{dx}+C=A(\frac{w_x}{w_y})^2+B\frac{w_x}{w_y}+C$

Then

$A(\frac{w_x}{w_y})^2+B\frac{w_x}{w_y}+C=0$

This conclude the proof.

In this last step i'm a very confused.  Why is this enough?

$A(\frac{w_x}{w_y})^2+B\frac{w_x}{w_y}+C=0$

The other question is how use the implicit function theorem.

Thanks for all!

Comment: Strange presentation, because implicit function theorem is only needed for ($\Leftarrow$) (not ($\Rightarrow$) direction) to show $w=k$ is (locally) a curve (they should have stated $w$ is $C^1$ with nonvanishing derivative).  If you know $w=k$ is a curve and $w_y\neq 0$, then $dy/dx=-w_x/w_y$ is just chain rule.

Comment: Can you be more explicit with the cain rule? @user10354138

Comment: What book did you see this theorem? I want to see this book. Thank you!